# SQL server - Finding duplicates on linked servers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find duplicates of the same database/table/column on two linked SQL servers
Note that the column may also have duplicates inside the table itself in each individual SQL server !

ie

server1.tableName.columnName:

```
john
john
mary
kate
kate
```

server2.tableName.columnName:

```
kate
```

I want the result in this case to be `kate` as it is the only entry that exists in both

I tried this:

```
select table1.columnName, table2.columnName, count(*) 
from [server1].[dbName].[dbo].[tableName] table1
inner join [server2].[dbName].[dbo].[tableName] table2
ON table1.columnName = table2.columnName
group by table1.columnName, table2.columnName having count(table1.columnName) > 1
```

Which gives a set of results

My question is is this correct ? 
will I get an entry for any value in `columnName` that exists in `dbName.tableName` on *both* server1 and server2 ?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  What do you mean by "duplicates".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will I get an entry for any value in columnName that exists in dbName.tableName on both server1 and server2 ?

Not exactly.  This would do what you want without the `having` -- the join is determining whether anything matches.

If you can leave the count out entirely, an alternative formulation uses `exists`:

```
select t1.columnName
from [server1].[dbName].[dbo].[tableName] t1
where exists (select 1
              from [server2].[dbName].[dbo].[tableName] t2
              where t1.columnName = t2.columnName
             );
```

Comment: thanks I get `The multi-part identifier "t2.columnName" could not be bound.` :(

Comment: @kofifus . . . I see.  You selected the value from the second table instead of the first in the `select`.  That is unnecessary, so I fixed the query.

Comment: Why not just `select t1.columnName from ...` ?

Answer (score 1):

No, you'd only get results which have a duplicate **within** one of the two servers and is present in both.

The linked servers here are irrelevant, your question functions the same on any two tables. I believe you're asking for one of the two below queries.

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE (Id INT)

DECLARE @table2 TABLE (Id INT)

INSERT INTO @table1 (Id)
VALUES (1), (2), (3)

INSERT INTO @table2 (Id)
VALUES (2), (2), (3), (4), (5), (5)

-- original query - 1 result
select table1.Id, table2.Id, count(*) 
from @table1 table1
inner join @table2 table2
ON table1.Id = table2.Id
group by table1.Id, table2.Id having count(table1.Id) > 1

-- cross table duplicates - 2 results
select table1.id
from @table1 table1
where exists (select 1 from @table2 table2 where table1.Id = table2.Id)

-- cross/within table duplicates - 3 results
select unioned.Id
from (
  select table1.Id
  from @table1 table1
  union all
  select table2.Id
  from @table2 table2
) unioned
group by unioned.Id
having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can left join the two tables on column name then select the column name from each table and exclude the null values.  This will show duplicates if they exist in the output otherwise use a distinct to remove the duplicates.